# TFS query to show all tasks by assignee

Tags: tfs, agile, tfs-workitem

I'm trying to create a view in TFS where I can see all tasks for the current Sprint by assignee. Preferably be able to expand and collapse each Assignee's section to reduce vertical scrolling. I don't see a way to create a Tree query with the Assignee Name as the parent and the tasks as children. It looks like the basis is always a Story. Is there a way to do this?
I know I can look at the Board view and filter by assignee but, that's a lot of clicks and scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?view=vsts) for your query. This will allow you to break the query down into assignees.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `group by` option in Work Item Queries.

You can only 'group by' work item type in tree and relation based queries. You'll need to resort to Excel to do the filtering or use PowerBI.